# Problema con llaves Foráneas poblando tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, tsql

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Cuando intento poblar dos tablas tengo el error 1452 Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTPLAN (
PLANNO varchar(8) not null,
EVENTNO varchar(8) not null,
WORKDATE date not null,
NOTES varchar(50),
ACTIVITY varchar(20) not null,
EMPNO varchar(8),
CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTPLAN PRIMARY KEY (PLANNO),
CONSTRAINT FK_EVENTNO FOREIGN KEY (EVENTNO) REFERENCES EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO),
CONSTRAINT FK_EMPNO FOREIGN KEY (EMPNO) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMPNO));
```

Me dice:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`COLLEAGEDB`.`EVENTPLAN`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EMPNO` FOREIGN KEY (`EMPNO`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE` (`EMPNO`))
```

Estos son los datos que intento ingresar:

```
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P100','E100',str_to_date('25,OCT,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Standard operation','Operation','E102');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P101','E104',str_to_date('03,DEC,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Watch for gate crashers','Operation','E100');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P102','E105',str_to_date('05,DEC,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Standard operation','Operation','E102');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P103','E106',str_to_date('12,DEC,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Watch for seat switching','Operation','E102');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P104','E101',str_to_date('26,OCT,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Standard cleanup','Cleanup','E101');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P105','E100',str_to_date('25,OCT,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Light cleanup','Cleanup','E101');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P199','E102',str_to_date('10,DEC,18','%d,%b,%y'),'ABC','Operation','E101');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P299','E101',str_to_date('26,OCT,18','%d,%b,%y'),null,'Operation','E101');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P349','E106',str_to_date('12,DEC,18','%d,%b,%y'),null,'Setup','E101');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P85','E100',str_to_date('25,OCT,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Standard operation','Cleanup','E102');
Insert into EVENTPLAN (PLANNO,EVENTNO,WORKDATE,NOTES,ACTIVITY,EMPNO) values ('P95','E101',str_to_date('26,OCT,18','%d,%b,%y'),'Extra security','Cleanup','E102');
```

Antes de intentar insertar esto, vi que todos los "Employees" aparecieran en la tabla de employees para que me halara la llave foránea como podrán ver acá:

```
Insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENT,EMAIL,PHONE) values ('E100','Chuck Coordinator','Administration','chuck@colorado.edu','3-1111');
Insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENT,EMAIL,PHONE) values ('E101','Mary Manager','Football','mary@colorado.edu','5-1111');
Insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENT,EMAIL,PHONE) values ('E102','Sally Supervisor','Planning','sally@colorado.edu','3-2222');
Insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENT,EMAIL,PHONE) values ('E103','Alan Administrator','Administration','alan@colorado.edu','3-3333');
```

Todos tienen EMPNO asociado.

Asimismo, tengo el error con esta otra tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTPLANLINE (
PLANNO varchar(8) not null,
LINENO varchar(8) not null,
TIMESTART datetime,
TIMEEND datetime,
NUMBERFLD varchar (30),
LOCNO varchar (8) not null, 
RESNO varchar (8) not null,     
CONSTRAINT TIMEVALIDATION check (TIMESTART > TIMEEND),
CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTPLANLINE PRIMARY KEY (LINENO),
CONSTRAINT FK_LOCNO FOREIGN KEY (LOCNO) REFERENCES LOCATION (LOCNO),
CONSTRAINT FK_PLANNO FOREIGN KEY (PLANNO) REFERENCES EVENTPLAN (PLANNO),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESNO FOREIGN KEY (RESNO) REFERENCES RESOURCETBL (RESNO));
```

Y me tira este error: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`COLLEAGEDB`.`EVENTPLANLINE`, CONSTRAINT `FK_LOCNO` FOREIGN KEY (`LOCNO`) REFERENCES `LOCATION` (`LOCNO`))

De nuevo, lo que trato de insertar es esto:

```
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P100',1, to_date('25-OCT-18 8:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('25-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L100','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P100',2, to_date('25-OCT-18 12:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('25-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 2,'L101','R101');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P100',3, to_date('25-OCT-18 7:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('25-OCT-18 16:30:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 1,'L102','R102');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P100',4, to_date('25-OCT-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('25-OCT-18 22:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L100','R102');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P101',1, to_date('3-DEC-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('3-DEC-18 20:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L103','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P101',2, to_date('3-DEC-18 18:30:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('3-DEC-18 19:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L105','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P101',3, to_date('3-DEC-18 19:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('3-DEC-18 20:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L103','R103');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P102',1, to_date('5-DEC-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('5-DEC-18 19:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L103','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P102',2, to_date('5-DEC-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('5-DEC-18 21:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L105','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P102',3, to_date('5-DEC-18 19:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('5-DEC-18 22:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L103','R103');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P103',1, to_date('12-DEC-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('12-DEC-18 21:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L103','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P103',2, to_date('12-DEC-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('12-DEC-18 21:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L105','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P103',3, to_date('12-DEC-18 19:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('12-DEC-18 22:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L103','R103');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P104',1, to_date('26-OCT-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('26-OCT-18 22:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L101','R104');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P104',2, to_date('26-OCT-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('26-OCT-18 22:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L100','R104');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P105',1, to_date('25-OCT-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('25-OCT-18 22:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L101','R104');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P105',2, to_date('25-OCT-18 18:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('25-OCT-18 22:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L100','R104');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P199',1, to_date('10-DEC-18 8:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('10-DEC-18 12:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),1,'L100','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P349',1, to_date('12-DEC-18 12:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('12-DEC-18 15:30:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),1,'L103','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P85',1,  to_date('25-OCT-18 9:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('25-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),5,'L100','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P85',2,  to_date('25-OCT-18 8:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('25-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L102','R101');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P85',3, to_date('25-OCT-18 10:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('25-OCT-18 15:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),3,'L104','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P95',1, to_date('26-OCT-18 8:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),  to_date('26-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L100','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P95',2, to_date('26-OCT-18 9:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),  to_date('26-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L102','R101');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P95',3, to_date('26-OCT-18 10:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('26-OCT-18 15:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),4,'L106','R100');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P95',4, to_date('26-OCT-18 13:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('26-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L100','R103');
Insert into EVENTPLANLINE (PLANNO,LINENO,TIMESTART,TIMEEND,NUMBERFLD,LOCNO,RESNO) values ('P95',5, to_date('26-OCT-18 13:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('26-OCT-18 17:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),2,'L101','R104');
```

Y antes de insertarlo verifiqué que todos los LOCNO (del error) estuviesen creados en la tabla LOCNO, como pueden ver acá:

```
Insert into LOCATION (LOCNO,FACNO,LOCNAME) values ('L100','F100','Locker room');
Insert into LOCATION (LOCNO,FACNO,LOCNAME) values ('L101','F100','Plaza');
Insert into LOCATION (LOCNO,FACNO,LOCNAME) values ('L102','F100','Vehicle gate');
Insert into LOCATION (LOCNO,FACNO,LOCNAME) values ('L103','F101','Locker room');
Insert into LOCATION (LOCNO,FACNO,LOCNAME) values ('L104','F100','Ticket Booth');
Insert into LOCATION (LOCNO,FACNO,LOCNAME) values ('L105','F101','Gate');
Insert into LOCATION (LOCNO,FACNO,LOCNAME) values ('L106','F100','Pedestrian gate');
```

Es decir, antes de insertar lo que dije, me aseguré de que LOCNO y EMPNO estuviesen apropiadamente poblados y que existiesen para que FK ligara los valores, pero no me deja. He intentado reescribir el código, hacer un drop de tabla, un truncate, volver a crear las llaves y al parecer nada soluciona el problema. He visto todas las páginas que tiran este error y hast he intentado hacer un alter table para cambiar la FK pero nada funciona. Perdón por la pregunta porque es súper grande, pero estoy súper desesperado.

Gracias!!!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tus tablas tienen mas de una llave foranea, y por lo que decis no chequeaste esas otras tablas...

Answer (score 0):

Este error puede darse cuando intentas agregar un registro en la llave foránea de la tabla **EVENTPLAN**, revisa si existe la tabla a la que haces referencia y que esa tabla contenga el dato al que hace referencia esa llave foránea.

Comment: Sí existe la tabla, de hecho verifiqué, pero no tengo idea de porqué aún con esa tabla sigue dando ese problema.

Comment: Entonces revisa que el dato de tu llave foránea se encuentre en la tabla que hace referencia.

Comment: Todos los datos que quiero insertar ya han sido insertados previamente en las tablas en las que hacen los FK.